# mysql merge timestamps from union into one timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that are joined together in a `UNION`. Each of the tables in the union has a column called `timestamp`. I need to merge together all the timestamp so they just appear as one column.

Here's my query so far;

```
SELECT ID, T.T_ID, T.name, T.pic, T.timestamp,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM track_plays WHERE T_ID = T.T_ID) AS plays,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM track_downloads WHERE T.T_ID) AS downloads,

NULL S_ID, NULL status, NULL timestamp,
NULL G_ID, NULL gig_name, NULL date_time, NULL lineup, NULL price, NULL currency, NULL G_pic, NULL ticket, NULL venue, NULL timestamp

FROM TRACKS T

UNION ALL
SELECT ID, NULL T_ID, NULL name, NULL pic, NULL timestamp, NULL plays, NULL downloads,
S.S_ID, S.status, S.timestamp,

NULL G_ID, NULL gig_name, NULL date_time, NULL lineup, NULL price, NULL currency, NULL G_pic, NULL ticket, NULL venue, NULL timestamp
FROM STATUS S

UNION ALL
SELECT ID, NULL T_ID, NULL name, NULL pic, NULL timestamp, NULL plays, NULL downloads,

NULL S_ID, NULL status, NULL S_ts,
G.G_ID, G.gig_name, G.date_time, G.lineup, G.price, G.currency, G.pic AS G_pic, G.ticket, G.venue, G.timestamp
FROM GIGS G
```

I'll make some examples but just with `ID` and timetamps.

**This is what I require**

```
ID    timestamp

1     2:00:00
2     5:00:00
3     9:32:00
```

**This is what happens at the moment**

```
ID    T.timestamp    S.Timestamp    G.timestamp

1     00:00:00       NULL           NULL
2     NULL           20:00:00       NULL
3     NULL           NULL           08:00:32
```

Comment: Which of the timestamps do you want to use?

Comment: @OmniPotens Each timestamp. So S.timestamp, G.timestamp and T.timestamp should be merged into one timestamp column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic approach (third column added if you would like to distinguish from where data came)

```
select ID, T.teimestamp, 1 from TRACKS T
UNION ALL 
select ID, S.teimestamp, 2 from STATUS S
UNION ALL 
select ID, G.teimestamp, 3 from GIGS G
```

as you can see you must place timestamps in the same column for every resource you add

Answer (score 1):

Try select each of the and give them same column names i.e. SELECT..... AS xname. You can see the SQL Documentation for this.

UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.

The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the column names for the results returned. Selected columns listed in corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same data type. (For example, the first column selected by the first statement should have the same type as the first column selected by the other statements.)

If the data types of corresponding SELECT columns do not match, the types and lengths of the columns in the UNION result take into account the values retrieved by all of the SELECT statements. For example, consider the following:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

```
mysql> SELECT REPEAT('a',1) UNION SELECT REPEAT('b',10);
+---------------+

| REPEAT('a',1) |
+---------------+
| a             |
| bbbbbbbbbb    |
+---------------+
```